# Xpath, selecting text from B inside div while also taking normal text

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

Basically I have html similar to this:

```
<div>
    <p>
        <b>1</b> Communication
    </p>
    <p>
        <b>2</b> Errors
    </p>
    ...
</div>
```

What I'm trying (with Scrapy) is something like:

```
response.xpath("//div//p//text()")
```

However this returns a list such as

```
[
    "1",
    "Communication",
    "2",
    "Errors"    
]
```

I want to have something like:

```
[
    "1 Communication",
    "2 Errors"
]
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I was trying to figure out a way to ignore the b tags, but I couldn't find anything that actually worked. The reason I can't just join the list indexes by two's is because not every html I need to parse works like this. I want to use something that could ignore the b tags if they exist, while just getting the text in p in any case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your general pattern is to ignore `<b>` tags, you could use [w3lib](http://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.html.remove_tags) to remove those tags and construct new response from the result. Something like:

```
import w3lib
import scrapy

new_body = w3lib.html.remove_tags(response.body, which_ones=('b'))
new_response = scrapy.http.HtmlResponse(url=response.url, body=new_body)
```

`new_response` now contains the original response but with `<b>` tags removed. You can then use extraction logic without the need to consider them.

Comment: This is exactly what I turned to. Thanks for mentioning it here!